# How to convert string to bytes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I extend the String class, and attach a method named `to_bytes`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ruby already has a `String#each_byte` method which is aliased to `String#bytes`.

Prior to Ruby 1.9 strings were equivalent to byte arrays, i.e. a character was assumed to be a single byte. That's fine for ASCII text and various text encodings like [Win-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) but fails badly with [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), which we see more and more often on the web. Ruby 1.9+ is Unicode aware, and strings are no longer considered to be made up of bytes, but instead consist of characters, which can be multiple bytes long.

So, if you are trying to manipulate text as single bytes, you'll need to ensure your input is ASCII, or at least a single-byte-based character set. If you might have multi-byte characters you should use `String#each_char` or `String.split(//)` or `String.unpack` with the `U` flag.

---

> What does // mean in `String.split(//)`

`//` is the same as using `''`. Either tells `split` to return characters. You can also usually use [`chars`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-chars).

Comment: `"фыв".bytes.to_a => [209, 132, 209, 139, 208, 178]` — bytes of unicode string. And asker wanted bytes, not characters. I see no problems. Or I don't see something?

Comment: Yes, and I said there are already `each_byte` and `bytes` methods available so there is no need to extend String with a `to_bytes` method. Regarding Unicode characters and bytes: Yes, you can convert the character into its component bytes easily, but you can not manipulate them like you would individual characters because some of the bytes are not character values but indicate how the character is modified. Anyone who is not aware of that and expects to treat text as bytes these days will have a great awakening when they encounter Unicode for the first time.

Comment: what does `//` meain in  `String.split(//)`?

Comment: `//` is the same as using `''`. Either tells `split` to return characters. You can also usually use `chars`.

Answer (score 50):

`String#bytes` returns enumerator through string bytes.

```
"asd".bytes
=> [97, 115, 100]
```

In Ruby 1.9.3 the `#bytes` was returning an Enumerator so you had to add `.to_a` to convert it to an Array. Since 2.3 or maybe even earlier you don't have to add it anymore.

Comment: The  `.to_a` is superfluous nowadays (`"asd".bytes.class === Array`)

Answer (score 5):

With the help of unpack we can convert the string into any format:- byte, bite(MSB,LSB), ASCII or hex. please go through this link:- 
http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/07/20/ruby-pack-unpack.html. To convert string into bytes:-

```
"abcde".unpack('c*')  
=> [97, 98, 99, 100, 101]
```