# How to convert a string to a byte array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to convert a string to a byte array before I can sign it with a private key but I have not done it before. My code is as below could anybody give me a clue on how I can do it. Thank you.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'digest/sha1'

@date = Date.today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
text_to_sign = "#{@order.phone_no}" + "#{@order.name}" + "#{@order.pay_type}" + "#{@order.pay_type}" + "1" + "MABIRA" + "81W30DI846" + "#{@date}" + "PULL" + "1" + "#{@cart.total_price}" + "#{@order.phone_no}" + ""
password = 'secret'

#converting the string to byte array
byte[] buff => new byte[1024]
text = buff.text_to_sign


private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('Private.key'), password)
ciphertext = private_key.private_encrypt(text)
ciphertext.encoding
signed_text = Base64.encode64(ciphertext).gsub("\n", '')
puts signed_text
signed_text
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to bytes in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103895/how-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6):

Ruby has the `bytes` method and you can convert that to an array with `to_a`
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-bytes

```
string = 'some string'
byte_array = string.bytes.to_a
# [115, 111, 109, 101, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```