# Convert String to Ruby byte array when using Hbase Shell

Tags: jruby, hbase-shell

I want to convert a String to a Ruby byte array.
I have a String and saving it in Hbase as binary byte array.
Need to scan with some filter on key which is a binary byte array.
Have a String like "U92w8GSBJ2BiHzGg" and need its representation like 
"\xFF\xA4\xDD\x13\x003\xE4\x85\xC7\x9D\xD5ZY\xF0\x1E" so that I can make query on Hbase shell like below

```
hbase(main):005:0> scan 't1', {FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('\xFF\xA4\xDD\x13\x003\xE4')"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to bytes in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103895/how-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to convert a String to a Ruby byte array.

will assume you mean: "want to convert a Ruby String to a Java byte array"

simply use `'a_ruby_binary_string'.to_java_bytes` (returns `byte[]` under JRuby)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is to use double quotes for JRuby byte strings. For example:

```
"\xFF\xA4\xDD\x13\x003\xE4"
```

(I know this reply is late, but I had the same problem and stumbled upon this solution)

Comment: 1. This works in other places in hbase shell (`STARTROW`, for example), but but in filter parameter it results in `TypeError: cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyString to class [B`
2. This does not really answer the question, as for the string "U92w8GSBJ2BiHzGg" you first need to figure out yourself what the corresponding bytes are